# I need to release a production app, the same app is in alpha mode

Tags: android, testing, production

I am done testing my app in alpha mode, whereby I was the only one that could see it. Now I intend to release the app to production app, I have two questions:

1. Can I delete the app that is in alpha mode
2. Or do I edit the alpha mode version and choose `release to production`, this is also an option at the top

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make changes in code then update version code and create a new release and if everything works as expected release Alpha to production.
In the first case it will start showing that your alpha version is superseded by the production version.